# How can I update multiple records which match with the Environ Username? Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to change the Status field to "Completed" where the environ username matches in the whole table and the table contains more than 400 records which matches approx 150 records with environ user name.

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset

set db = currentdb
set rs = db.OpenRecordset("UPDATE * from Upload_Report set status = '" & Completed & "' Where Analyst = '" & Environ("Username") & "'")

If Not rs.EOF then
    MsgBox "Records were updated!", VBInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Match not found", VBExclamation
End if

End sub
```

The code throws

> "Run-time error '3078':
> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'UPDATE * from Upload_Report set status = 'completed' where Analyst = '*****'". Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

I cross verified with my table (Upload_Report) and no spelling errors are identified.

How can I update multiple records which match with the Environ Username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenRecordset is used for reading.

What you want is db.[Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao) "UPDATE ..."

Comment: Now it is showing compile error: expected function or variable. I'm new to this. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: "Execute doesn't return a Recordset."

So, you have to remove "set rs = " and the if block after the execute.

Comment: Addition to that how can I add if statement whether the records doesn't math with environment user?